# How can i add to the resources duplicate files with different content?

Tags: c#

On my hard disk I have 5 directories named: test1 , test2 ,test3 ,test4 and test5.
In each directory I have two xml files name: test.xml and testing.xml. Each file in every directory has different content !

Now in my project I need to add the files from each directory to the resources.
But when I try to add them, I'm getting a message that the files are the same and if I want to replace them.

Can I create directories in the resources? I have to keep the files names to be the same! Tried to google about embeded or something but I didn't understand.

What else can I do to keep the files names and still use them each one ?

Answer (score 0):

How you are planning to access if all files of same name is added to same resource? To access different file you must have different logic, either by namespace or prefix or suffix to file name. So design in same way.